# Filter design for a bridge rectifier for battery charging

Tags: batteries, filter, charger

I want to charge a battery bank having voltage 114 V DC. My transformer output is 125 V single phase AC (176 V amplitude) I give this supply to bridge rectifier. Now I don't know how to design an RC filter which gives me 123-128 V DC output to charge this battery bank. Without any filter the full wave pulsating DC output of bridge rectifier reaches 176 V slowly and this would destroy the battery bank due to over voltage charging. The problem is I can't change the transformer output. It is fixed to 125 V(rms). The image shows a filter design in similar battery charger but I don't know how it functions to reduce voltage to 123 V DC which safely charge my battery[image: The image shows a filter design in similar battery charger but I don't know how it functions to reduce voltage to 123 V DC which safely charge my battery]

Comment: To achieve what you want you are going to need a large smoothing inductor or some high-power voltage regulation circuit.

Comment: What type of batteries?

Comment: VRLA Lead Acid batteries, 120Ah